# How could I download an mms audio stream in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, streaming, media

I would like to access an mms:// url, and stream the file in ruby.  For example,
in the same way that Net:HTTP works for http:// type urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpliest (but non-scalable) way is to ask `MPlayer` to `-dumpstream` it for you.

http://mplayerhq.hu/